# find an object in Array of Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

if i want for an example loop Through this Array to find specific item in Items Array how to approach that? i made this logic but it doesn't work

```
DATA.map((D)=>{
    return D.items.find((item)=>{
       return item.name ==='Blue Beanie'
    })
  })
```

this is the Array plus how to create new ONE array includes the both of items arrays to be like that: items: [{
id: 1,
name: 'Brown Brim',
price: 25
},
{
id: 2,
name: 'Blue Beanie',
price: 18
},
{
id: 3,
name: 'Adidas NMD',
price: 220
},
{
id: 4,
name: 'Adidas Yeezy',
price: 280
}
]

```
const DATA= [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'Hats',
    routeName: 'hats',
    items: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Brown Brim',
        price: 25
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Blue Beanie',
        price: 18
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: 'Sneakers',
    routeName: 'sneakers',
    items: [
      {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Adidas NMD',
        price: 220
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        name: 'Adidas Yeezy',
        price: 280
      }
             ]
  }
];
```

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: An object which its name ==='Blue Beanie' :{
        id: 2,
        name: 'Blue Beanie',
        price: 18
      }

Answer (score 0):

Transform `DATA` into list of items and find from that list your expected item

```
const res = DATA.flatMap((D) => D.items).find(
  (item) => item.name === "Brown Brim"
)
```

```js
const DATA = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "Hats",
    routeName: "hats",
    items: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: "Brown Brim",
        price: 25,
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "Blue Beanie",
        price: 18,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "Sneakers",
    routeName: "sneakers",
    items: [
      {
        id: 3,
        name: "Adidas NMD",
        price: 220,
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        name: "Adidas Yeezy",
        price: 280,
      },
    ],
  },
]

const res = DATA.flatMap((D) => D.items).find(
  (item) => item.name === "Brown Brim"
)

console.log(res)
```

---

**Reference**

[Array.prototype.flatMap()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)

Answer (score 0):

As for the first question "loop Through this Array to find a specific item in Items Array"
given it is not sorted in any way, this can be done by iterating over the DATA array and search inside the items
If want to have access to the item from the outside of the 'forEach' scope you have to declare the variable outside

Regarding the second question, use the reduce function while iterating the array

**NOTE:** You can obviously combine both tasks as you already iterate through the array, so no need to do it twice. But to avoid confusion, I separated the logic.
Also, if you do choose to combine the tasks, using the reduce is not relevant, but very much like the answer to the first question, you can declare a buffer such as an array, and just copy items to it on the go (I'll leave out questions on performance for that matter)

```js
const DATA = [
  {
    id: 1, title: 'Hats', routeName: 'hats',
    items: [
      {id: 1,name: 'Brown Brim',price: 25},
      {id: 2,name: 'Blue Beanie',price: 18}
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2, title: 'Sneakers', routeName: 'sneakers',
    items: [
      {id: 3,name: 'Adidas NMD',price: 220},
      {id: 4,name: 'Adidas Yeezy',price: 280}
    ]
  }
];

//Question 1
//creating the object that will hold the item
//outside of the 'forEach' scope so we can use it later
let res = {};
const searchRes = DATA.forEach(entry => {
  entry.items.forEach(item => {
    if (item.name === 'Brown Brim')
      //duplicating the item to a variable declared outside of this scope
      res = { ...item
      };
  });
});
console.log(`Q1 - The item we found:`);
console.log(res);

// Question 2
// Merging all object inside the 'items' array using Reduce
const merged = DATA.reduce((acc, curr) =>
  acc.concat(curr.items), []);
console.log(`Q2 - The merged array:`);
console.log(merged)
```

Comment: @khdeveloperj, Hi, You're welcome. in that case, please approve the answer as an answer to your question

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is helpful?

```js
const DATA= [
  {id: 1,title:'Hats',routeName:'hats',
   items:[{id: 1,name:"Brown Brim",price:25},
          {id: 2,name: 'Blue Beanie',price: 18}]},
  {id: 2,title: 'Sneakers',routeName: 'sneakers',
   items: [{id: 3,name: 'Adidas NMD',price: 220},
           {id: 4,name: 'Adidas Yeezy',price: 280}]}
];
console.log(DATA.map(D=>D.items.find(item=>item.name==='Brown Brim'))
                .filter(e=>e))
```

The `.map` returns either an element matching your criterion or `undefined`, The chained `.filter` then removes all "falsy" elements, i. e. all the `undefined` ones.